# Xamarin IOS bluetooth scan not showing all device list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am not getting all devices when I am trying to scan Bluetooth devices with my application. It does not show android and windows device list. I have attached screenshots to understand my problem.

Here is my code.

```
_centralManager = new CBCentralManager(DispatchQueue.CurrentQueue);
_centralManager.DiscoveredPeripheral += _centralManager_DiscoveredPeripheral;    
_centralManager.UpdatedState += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
       var manager = sender as CBCentralManager;
       if (manager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
             _centralManager.ScanForPeripherals(new CBUUID[0]);
};
```

Scan event:

```
public void _centralManager_DiscoveredPeripheral(object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e)
{
     var device = e.Peripheral;
     var rssi = e.RSSI;
     var ads = e.AdvertisementData;           
}
```

Note: In my app, I was show device which name is not equal to null or blank.

[image: App bluetooth scanning result]

[image: IOS bluetooth scanning result]

Comment: Have you tried to use other bluetooth app to scan your android devices? Are these android devices using BLE?

Comment: I am not sure about BLE. But I tried to with my windows phone and other android devices but it was not showing in my app and showing in setting Bluetooth menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented GATTA server on an Android device and it worked.
First, run the app on an Android device, start the server and done.

https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver/blob/master/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/gattserver/GattServerActivity.java

In my case, I wanted to do this for android things. So I implemented the code in android things.